# Parse-server I/O failure message with S9 device, working with others

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-server

When trying to send a request to parse server it usually works, however with an S9 device, I get I/O failure error message. This message usually appears when there is no internet connection on the device. However, I made sure that the phone is connected to the internet and tried with both wifi and 4G.

parse-server version: 3.1.3
android parse:  1.18.5

Answer (score 0):

```
 Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("")
                .clientKey("")
                .server("https://thisisatest.herokuapp.com/parse/") // https instead of http
                .build()
        );
```

Using https instead of http in the server url fixed the issue.